# Flycheck: change color / thickness of underline

Tags: flycheck

Using Flycheck, I get a green thin jagged underline line for style-guide violations, and a red thin jagged underline for syntax errors (see below).

[image]

Is it possible to change the thickness or the color of the line? Namely, I'd like the red to be more noticeable upon my grey background. I would prefer if it was light red / pink instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the color but you cannot change the thickness.

There are two ways:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>list-faces-display</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>, find `flycheck-error` click it, edit the underline color -> *Apply and Save*
2. You can add some piece of code to your `init` file:

   `(set-face-attribute 'flycheck-error nil :underline '(:color "red2" :style wave))` where `red2` is the color used.